# Передача файла из input с помощью AJAX в IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, blob

Цель - передать файл ajax-запросом на Web-API с помощью javascript/jquery в браузере IE 8-9.
К странице подключен [FileAPI](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI), происходит эмуляция *FormData()* для браузеров, которые их не поддерживают, а чтобы все это работало на html5 - еще подключается *html5shiv*.

Работающий код для Google Chrome и IE>10 следующий:

```js
function upload_scan(address, id) {
    var input = document.getElementById(address);
    var file = FileAPI.getFiles(input);
    var temp = new FormData();
    temp.append('picture', file[0]);
    if (id == undefined) id = '';
    else id = '/' + id;
    $.ajax({
      url: string_connection + 'uploadfile' + id,
      type: "POST",
      data: temp,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        //Код при выполнении
      },
      error: function(x, y, z) {
        alert('Не получилось загрузить скан\n' + x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
      }
    });
```

```html
<pre>
<form name="scan" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
  <input type="file" id="scan_file" class="btn" accept="image/*">
  <input id="button_for_scan" type="button" value="Загрузить" onclick="upload_scan('scan_file');">
</form>
</pre>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что метод FileAPI.getFiles() в браузерах IE 8-9 берет не файл, а пустой **blob**. Есть предложение, как это все реализовать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. клонируете файловый `<input>`
2. отсоединяете старый `<input>` (который с файлом)
3. присоединяете новый `<input>` на место старого
4. присоединяете старый `<input>` к вспомогательной форме
5. настраиваете для вспомогательной формы target, чтобы он указывал на скрытый `<iframe>`
6. сабмитите форму

Вот тут можно увидеть готовую реализацию: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js#L53